# How Can I Run The Topaz SigWeb Demo?

Tags: topaz-signatures

I am using Topaz e-signature and Im trying to append it in my web application. When I tried to test it on this link: https://www.sigplusweb.com/sigweb_httptest.htm, unfortunately it doesnt work. No signature has appeared on the web but when I tried testing it on DemoOCX.exe, it works fine there.

This is my signature pad model:
Topaz Siglite 1x5 - USB
T-S460-HSB-R

Im using Windows 7 and 32 bit operating system.

Can anyone point me, somewhere on the web, which is a working demonstration of Topaz signature.And if none exist, a bit of working code that can initiate or sign on the web, would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the appropriate driver for the Topaz model you have? I'm working on a Topaz project as well and the demos work fine for me. Download the drivers here: https://www.topazsystems.com/sigweb.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is you have to put your code on server not local html file. I have met the same issue before and contacted with Topaz tech support, they said if it's on server, then it should work.